# How to analyse response time graph

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing

I have done a load test with JMeter. Following is my Response Time Graph.

```
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXnXz.png
```

How can I be able to analyse the test result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph tells that in first minute of your test response time was between 10 and 20 seconds, after that it settled down and was < 0.5 second. Consider 3 things:

- You have yellow exclamation sign with "1" at upper-right corner. Check *jmeter.log* file to determine the cause, it may be critical.
- Set reasonable [ramp-up time](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#thread_group) so both JMeter and application under test could "warm-up"
- Don't use JMeter GUI to run load tests, use it only for tests development and debugging. Run JMeter tests in [command-line mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) and consider following other recommendations from [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) guide.
- You have yellow exclamation sign

Answer (score 0):

- If you want to export the data of your graph, it is just above the graph in `Write results to file`. You will have `csv` file of each point
- If you want to have the statistics of every call, you should add the Listener `View Results in Table` where you could export the data in a file.
- If you don't know how to read this graph, it is you're average response time every 10 seconds.

You could also add the Listner `Summary Report` to have global stats of the whole test.

Comment: i tried saving it in csv format. It says, `Error loading results file`

Comment: You have to specify the file name before starting your test. It will write in the file during the test.